# TeamCity: shows build from two VCS roots but I have only one

Tags: teamcity

In my build log I'm getting the message "Collecting changes in 2 VCS roots", however there should be only one root.  How do I find and eliminate the incorrect root (this is an extremely large project with dependencies on other builds).  The details of the two listed roots in the build log I can summarize as:

[VCS Root details] "RRR Release Branch"...parent id=SSS_FFF_MMM...description: "svn:....AAA_Dev"

[VCS Root details] "RRR Release Branch...parent id=SSS_MMM...description: "svn:....AAA_Release"

I want the first listed root and its SVN branch, but not the second.  However, I cannot find it within the "RRR Release Branch" project even though I have looked at all the VCS root ID settings trying to find a match for "SSS_MMM".

A clue as to what may have caused this (as I'm new to TeamCity) is that I do see a notice at the bottom of the Edit VCS Root page where it prompts me select between "Apply to Release package only (a copy of this VCS root will be created" and "Apply to all build configurations and templates".  I believe I selected the first one, encountered problems, and then selected the second one.  I notice that whatever I do, the notice still appears and doesn't go away.

Comment: Most probably you have some builds chain (snapshot dependencies) which have both vcs roots, so TeamCity is checking for changes in both of them to correctly understand 'snapshot'

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I was able to discover where the other root was.  To help anyone having this same issue, I will describe what I did, which is this: I went to Administration > Projects and then selected < Root project >.  In that configuration I selected "VCS Roots", which then listed all of the roots in use, which projects they belonged to, and how many usages of a root existed.  From that, I was able to find the root I was looking for.